# Is it possible to change a Wordpress/woocommerce title that is written with uppercase to appear capitalized?

Tags: php, css, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently working on a project that is based on WordPress and as an e-commerce platform, it uses WooCommerce. I made a product migration from an old site that has the product titles written in uppercase.

Currently I have this html code for the titles inside a product:

```html
<h1 class="product_title netry-title">PRODUCT TITLE</h1>
```

So I want the product title to appear like "Product Title". Is there any way to make this happen?

I saw some answers that use JS or JQuery, but did not work for me.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853335/uppercase-issue-for-title-in-wordpress

Comment: Is it possible to use something like `echo ucwords(strtolower('PRODUCT TITLE'));` via PHP? Output: `Product Title`.

Comment: Sounds like fixing it once in database would make most sense

Comment: With PHP using [`ucfirst()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853335/uppercase-issue-for-title-in-wordpress), or maybe using CSS  `text-transform` property: [Make the first character Uppercase in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577364/make-the-first-character-uppercase-in-css/5577380#5577380)… **The best solution is to fix that in database** as @charlietfl mention.

Comment: @maniksidana I tried this but this will make only the first letter uppercase. I want something like e.g "Product Title Test". The first letter of every word to be Capital letter.

Comment: @charlietfl. is it possible to be done with any query directly in DB? This must be automated as we speak for at least 1000 products.

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky I will try and add it in the woocommerce template and see if it works that way.

Comment: Yes...there are even worpress plugins you can use to modify entries in db, or write your own queries in php to clean it up

Comment: @charlietfl I will go make a search about this and get back with a answer.

Comment: Mostly covered by "[Turn all titles in wordpress powered site into "Capitalized" case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3033988/90527)"

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why is this tagged with PHP, CSS, SQL, while you haven't shared any related code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging into this and with the help from @outis that pointed me to another post i had the outcome that i wanted. What i was asking was mostly covered here "[Turn all titles in wordpress powered site into "Capitalized" case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033988/turn-all-titles-in-wordpress-powered-site-into-capitalized-case)"

Below is the answer from that post (as presented from the user brendan):

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS proper;
SET GLOBAL  log_bin_trust_function_creators=TRUE;
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION proper( str VARCHAR(128) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(128)
BEGIN
  DECLARE c CHAR(1);
  DECLARE s VARCHAR(128);
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE BOOL INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE punct CHAR(17) DEFAULT ' ()[]{},.-_!@;:?/';
  SET s = LCASE( str );
  WHILE i < LENGTH( str ) DO 
    BEGIN
      SET c = SUBSTRING( s, i, 1 );
      IF LOCATE( c, punct ) > 0 THEN
        SET BOOL = 1;
      ELSEIF BOOL=1 THEN 
        BEGIN
          IF c >= 'a' AND c <= 'z' THEN 
            BEGIN
              SET s = CONCAT(LEFT(s,i-1),UCASE(c),SUBSTRING(s,i+1));
              SET BOOL = 0;
            END;
          ELSEIF c >= '0' AND c <= '9' THEN
            SET BOOL = 0;
          END IF;
        END;
      END IF;
      SET i = i+1;
    END;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN s;
END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

I twicked this a bit and removed the `SET GLOBAL  log_bin_trust_function_creators=TRUE;` because of the limitation i had on the server. (Shared Hosting Server).

After that i had to target the titles of the products only. So i changed the default SQL from the post to this

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title = proper(post_title) WHERE `post_type` LIKE 'product';
```

Also did the same `product_variation` as there where some Variation products in the shop.

I then had to regenerate the database lookup form inside woocommerce

> (Admin dashboard ->Woocommerce -> Status -> Tools -> Product lookup
> tables : Regenarate) and a Term counts (Inside Tools as well).

In some cases it might be needed to Update database (this is also inside Tools tab), **but before you do anything of the above, make sure to have a backup of your database.**

As a general info, product meta values are also stored in `wp_postmeta` table with `post_id` as relational index (the product ID). But if nothing of the above works, then try to update also the `wp_postmeta` using an SQL Query.

As i mentioned before, **always backup your Database and then start working with tests**.